# How to make the lines numbers of logic proofs be added paratheses?

Tags: logic, logicproof

A MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{logicproof}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%%%make logic proof lines ragged left%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\patchcmd{\logicproof}{\center}{\flushleft}{}{}
\patchcmd{\endlogicproof}{\endcenter}{\endflushleft}{}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{logicproof}{1}
        \forall x \, (P(x) \to Q(x)) & premise \label{cxy}\\
        \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
        P(x_0) \to Q(x_0) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{e}$ 1 \\
        P(x_0) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{e}$ 2 \\
        Q(x_0) & $\to \mathrm{e}$ 3, 4 and so on \eqref{cxy}\\
        \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5
\end{logicproof}
\end{document}
```

And its output is

[image]

My **QUESTION** is *how to make the lines numbers of logic proofs be added parentheses, such as (1), (2), (3) and so on*？I tried several times but unfortunately failed.

Any reply is welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro that holds the format of the line number in the proofs is `\lp@start@proof@line`. You only need to redefine it:

```
\renewcommand{\lp@start@proof@line}{%
  \stepcounter{lp@line}%
  (\arabic{lp@line})%
  &%
  \lp@continue@proof@line%
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{logicproof}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%%%make logic proof lines ragged left%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\patchcmd{\logicproof}{\center}{\flushleft}{}{}
\patchcmd{\endlogicproof}{\endcenter}{\endflushleft}{}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\lp@start@proof@line}{%
  \stepcounter{lp@line}%
  (\arabic{lp@line})%
  &%
  \lp@continue@proof@line%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{logicproof}{1}
        \forall x \, (P(x) \to Q(x)) & premise \label{cxy}\\
        \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
        P(x_0) \to Q(x_0) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{e}$ 1 \\
        P(x_0) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{e}$ 2 \\
        Q(x_0) & $\to \mathrm{e}$ 3, 4 and so on \eqref{cxy}\\
        \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5
\end{logicproof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, how do you read your surname "Oleinik"?

Comment: @M.Logic More or less like it's written, with stress on “lei”.  Google translate's pronunciation for “Olejnik” in Polish is pretty accurate (my last name is of Polish origin).

Comment: O read as in so or as in off?

Comment: @M.Logic If I had to choose, I'd pick “so” (definitely not “off”), but it's shorter, more like the “o” in “word”.  Mind if I ask why you want to know? (I'm getting curious on your curiosity :)

Comment: I'd like to show thanks to people who help me a lot on latex when writing my book, and I need to translate it into Chinese from the exact sound of surname. I see, so it pronounced [ɔ]?

Comment: @M.Logic Oh, nice :D  I'd say it's pronounced [o] ([this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_back_rounded_vowel))